# Form who contain 2 actions (not normal)

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jquery-ui, jsp

I have a form who display information and web user can enter some param to launch a query on the server.
Also, web user can create a new user, so i have another form for this.

To display a web page a do

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/secure/admin/csvUser")
public String csvUserView(Model model, Locale locale) {
    model.addAttribute("userBeanList", userBeanMap);

    model.addAttribute("addUserBean", new UserBean());

    return VIEW_CSV_USER;
 }
```

on my web page i have

```
<c:url var="downloadUsertUrl" value="/secure/downloadcsvUser/" />
<c:url var="deleteUserUrl" value="/secure/deleteUser/" />
<c:url var="addUserUrl" value="/secure/addUser/" />
```

UserBeanList is displayed with this code

```
<form id="formUser" action="${downloadUserUrl}">
<c:forEach var="userBeans" items="${userBeanList}" varStatus="statusUser">
    <tr data-username="${userBeans.key}">
      <td>${statusUser.count}</td>
          <td>${userBeans.value.userTitle}</td>
          <td align="center">
    <button type="button" id="updateUserButton${statusUser.count}"></button>
            <button type="button" id="deleteUserButton${statusUser.count}"></button>
            <input id="downloadUserButton${statusUser.count}" type="image" height="25" width="25" src="${contextPath}/resources/images/addUser.png"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</form>
```

When i click on Add user this dialog open

```
<div id="createUser" title="Add a user" style="display:none">
  <fieldset>I do 
<form:form actions="${addUserUrl}" modelAttribute="addUserBean">

         ...

    </form:form>

  </fieldset>
</div>

I have problem with this form, it generated with two actions, one with this url: /secure/addUser/ and one with /secure/admin/csvUser
I don't understand why
```

Comment: What are you using for code generation?

Comment: only spring... <form:form are from spring...

Answer (score 0):

seem like a crap was in cache or something similar, i restarted my ide and it was fine